# setViewControllers does not set the correct orientation based on the topViewController

Tags: ios6, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, rotation

I use a `UINavigationController` to present content in my app. I keep my controllers in a separate dictionary and, upon user interaction, I load the navigation controller with the proper `UIViewContoller`. Each view controller implements the

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutoRotate;
```

and

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations;
```

But when I try to set a view controller to my navigation controller like this:

```
[self setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:controller] animated:NO];
```

the application does not rotate based on the controller's supported orientations

For example, the phone is in landscape orientation and my view controller supports only portrait.
How can I make the device rotate to portrait?

Code:
My navigation controller subclass

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    return [[self topViewController] shouldAutorotate];
}


- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return [[self topViewController] supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}


- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentatio{
    return [[self topViewController] preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
}
```

My controller:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    return YES;
}


- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{    
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}


- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

The documentation states that in order to call `supportedInterfaceOrientations`, `shouldAutorotate` must return YES.

Any ideas??